# cassandra: strategy for single datacenter deployment

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

We are planning to use apache shiro & cassandra for distributed session management very similar to  mentioned @ https://github.com/lhazlewood/shiro-cassandra-sample

Need advice on deployment for cassandra in Amazon EC2:

In EC2, we have below setup:
Single region, 2 Availability Zones(AZ), 4 Nodes

Accordingly, cassandra is configured:
Single DataCenter: DC1
two Racks:         Rack1, Rack2
4 Nodes:           Rack1_Node1, Rack1_Node2, Rack2_Node1, Rack2_Node2

Data Replication Strategy used is **NetworkTopologyStrategy**

Since Cassandra is used as session datastore, **we need high consistency and availability**.

**My Questions:**

1. How many replicas shall I keep in a cluster? 
   Thinking of 2 replicas, 1 per rack.
2. What shall be the consistency level(CL) for read and write operations? 
   Thinking of QUORUM for both read and write, considering 2 replicas in a cluster.
3. In case 1 rack is down, would Cassandra write & read succeed with the above configuration? 
   I know it can use the hinted-hands-off for temporary down node, but does it work for both read/write operations?
4. Any other suggestion for my requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally going for an even number of nodes is not the best idea, as is going for an even number of availability zones. In this case, if one of the racks fails, the entire cluster will be gone. I'd recommend to go for 3 racks with 1 or 2 nodes per rack, 3 replicas and QUORUM for read and write. Then the cluster would only fail if two nodes/AZ fail.

Comment: With 2 nodes in 2 racks/AZ, If 1 rack goes down, would Cassandra write & read succeed with CL=QOURUM and using NetworkTopologyStrategy?

Comment: I'm afraid it won't work, as half your cluster will be down. Check http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/cluster_architecture/replication#networktopologystrategy for details on the NTS.

Comment: This seems interesting...http://www.datastax.com/doc-source/developer/java-driver/reference/automaticFailover_r.html , You can hint the driver to try with downgraded consistency level!! Seems great feature, luving cassandra!!

Answer (score 0):

You probably have heard of the CAP theorem in database theory. If not, You may learn the details about the theorem in wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem, or just google it. It says for a distributed database with multiple nodes, a database can only achieve two of the following three goals: consistency, availability and partition tolerance.

Cassandra is designed to achieve high availability and partition tolerance (AP), but sacrifices consistency to achieve that. However, you could set consistency level to *all* in Cassandra to shift it to CA, which seems to be your goal. Your setting of quorum 2 is essentially the same as "all" since you have 2 replicas. But in this setting, if a single node containing the data is down, the client will get an error message for read/write (not partition-tolerant).

You may take a look at a video here to learn some more (it requires a datastax account): [https://academy.datastax.com/courses/ds201-cassandra-core-concepts/introduction-big-data](https://academy.datastax.com/#/courses)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yeah, have learned about CAP and how cassandra operates over last 2 years ;-)